# prevent inputAccessoryView from displaying when presenting viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, resignfirstresponder, inputaccessoryview

I have a `viewController` with an `inputAccessoryView` that is displayed as below:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
   get {
       return myInputView
   }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
   return true
}
```

I can easily show and hide this `inputAccessoryView` by using `self.becomeFirstResponder()` and `self.resignFirstResponder()`

The problem I have is when the `viewController` is first presented (instantiated from storyboard), the `inputAccessoryView` is visible.  I can only dismiss it in `viewDidAppear` using `self.resignFirstResponder()`.  This shows it moving down with an animation.

I am guessing that a `viewController` automatically becomes `firstResponder` when it is presented, but wondering how I can override that before `viewWillAppear`.  There is no effect in putting the `self.resignFirstResponder` method in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Couldn't you load and assign the inputAccessoryView in your view did load? 
that way it won't be loaded from the nib

Comment: the problem is that the viewController is firstResponder and I have no way to undo that until the viewController is on screen.  I need to assign the inputAccessoryView in the getter of the inputAccessoryView variable for it to work as I want.

Comment: Ah, what about hiding it and unhiding it once it disappears.
I know, seems hacky

Comment: I have done a version of that.  Basically I set a bool to indicate when I require the inputAccessoryView.  in the getter if the bool is false, I return nil otherwise return the accessoryView.  it works fine but I prefer to know how to control the viewController's firstResponder state and have a cleaner solution to this.

Comment: @alionthego just add a bool property `var firstResponder = false` to your view controller and set it to true inside viewDidAppear method. and change canBecomeFirstResponder method to `override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
   return firstResponder
}`

Comment: that is a workable solution but I also have the same problem when popping a pushed viewController back to this viewController.  I could modify the firstResponder variable you suggested when pushing but it starts to get a bit messy.  I will stick with the bool variable inside the inputAccessoryView getter.  btw, coolest profile picture ever!  got to put on some rush...

Comment: @alionthego have you solved this problem ?